# Occasional BadRequest calling CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync on Azure NotificationHubClient

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

We support Push Notifications on iOS and Android and are using Azure Notifcation Hub to send those notifications.

Our apps call our ASPNET Web Api which calls the Notification Hub using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs package (ver 4.1.0). The DeviceIdentity class used below is our model and we just copy the values into the NotificationHubs' Installation object.

```
public async Task<string> CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(DeviceIdentity deviceIdentity, CancellationToken token)
{
    var installation = new Installation()
    {
        InstallationId = deviceIdentity.InstallationId,
        PushChannel = deviceIdentity.PushChannel,
        Tags = deviceIdentity.Tags
    };

    if (installationPlatform.TryGetValue(deviceIdentity.Platform, out var platform))
    {
        installation.Platform = platform;
    }
    else
    {
        return "Platform not found in installationPlatform dictionary";
    }            

    try
    {
        await azureHub.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation, token);
        return null;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        this.logger.LogError(e, "CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync failed with" + e.Message);
        return e.Message;
    }
}
```

99% of the time the call to CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync works but this week we noticed it fail and looking back through Application Insights over the last 90 days it failed 43 times on 4 days, in our test environment. The error was

> Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Messaging.BadRequestException
>
> Installation validation failed with following error(s): One or more
> characters in device token is not a hexadecimal
> digit...TrackingId:ac5057aa-fc41-41bf-857a-9d90613b8106_G1,TimeStamp:2/20/2023
> 5:18:39 PM

I logged out the value that is being added used for the PushChannel and it is indeed a non-BASE64 value however this call almost always works and I do not see any of the samples BASE64 encode the value.

Should we be always BASE64 encoding it?